# CSS class not working as expected

Tags: jquery, css

My HTML codes not implement the CSS styling..The border in the CSS file is not being implemented.
I tried both in Firefox & IE. Please provide your inputs.

Please find the code below:

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="file://c:/jquery/chapter-1/begin/styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header" class="no_hover"><h1>Header</h1></div>
        <button type="button" id="btn1">Click to Add</button>
        <button type="button" id="btn2">Click to Remove</button>
        <script src="file://c:/jquery/chapter-1/begin/scripts/jquery.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="file://c:/jquery/chapter-1/begin/scripts/test4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

jS FILE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click( function(){
        $("#header").addClass("hover");
        $("#header").removeClass("no_hover");
    });
    $("#btn2").click( function(){
        $("#header").removeClass("hover");
        $("#header").addClass("no_hover");
    });
});
```

CSS FILE

```
.hover{
    border: solid #f00 3px;
}
.no_hover{
    border: solid #000 3px;
}
```

Comment: Does the browser's error console print an error that it couldn't gather the stylesheet? I guess so. Maybe it helps to add a third slash behind `file://`.

Comment: Do you really need to have two styles?  IF they are redefining the same thing (border) you only need to reverse the sequence of the CSS .hover and .no_hover, then toggle the .hover one as it will replace the .no_hover (reverse due to your default .no_hover)

Comment: I guess the shorthand of border is : 
border: 1px #000 solid;

Comment: See this for an example of my comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nq3Hp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to help you with your jQuery or to clean it up.  Don't dive into the DOM multiply  times.  If you are then create a variable.  Also you can chain your events.  It looks like you are just starting jQuery so when you get more into it you will learn this.  Hope this helps.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCKTd/9/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var header = $("#header");

    $("#btn1").on("click", function() {
       header.addClass("hover").removeClass("no_hover");                      
    });
    $("#btn2").on("click", function() {
        header.removeClass("hover").addClass("no_hover");
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably in the fact that you are linking to the files as paths to the file system... you want to instead link to the `CSS` and `JS` files as virtual paths off your web server.

Your code works. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/x4zda/

Comment: I tried in your fiddle but it does not work..Looks like a browser issue..Do I need to enable anything on my browser.

Comment: what browser are you using? I tried in Chrome, FF and IE9

Comment: It works in Firefox-11.0 and not in IE-9.

Comment: It definitely works in IE9 on a Win7 and WinXP machine.

Comment: IE9 doesn't exist for Windows XP.

Comment: Just an FYI on your fiddle, this works: `$("#header").toggleClass("hover no_hover");` with a space separator to toggle and avoid separate ones.

Comment: @BramVanroy yes, a typo, IE8 on XP and IE9 on win7.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Cool!! thanks for that tip! Fiddle updated!

Comment: very strange, I have a IE-9..

Answer (score 0):

Working fine when you localise your `js` and `CSS` files.

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCKTd/2/)

Try the following code which includes everything within one page.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #header {}
        .hover{
         border: solid #f00 3px;
        }
        .no_hover{
         border: solid #000 3px;
        }
    </style>
 </head>

 <body>

  <div id="header" class="no_hover"><h1>Header</h1></div>
  <button type="button" id="btn1">Click to Add</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn2">Click to Remove</button>



  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

     <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btn1").click(function() {
                $("#header").addClass("hover");
                $("#header").removeClass("no_hover");
            });
            $("#btn2").click(function() {
                $("#header").removeClass("hover");
                $("#header").addClass("no_hover");
            });
        });
     </script>
 </body>
</html>​
```